# Highcharts-Vue wait for data then update series

Tags: vue.js, highcharts

There seems to be a few examples of how to do something similar, but all slightly different from my case. I am loading some stock data from an API (in a JS file) and then using it in my VUE. I would like to update my chart series with a new array compiles from the API data, but it's not working and I am not getting any errors.

My Vue looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <highcharts :options="chartOptions" :updateArgs="[true, false]" ref="highcharts"></highcharts>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import appService from '../stock_prices'
    import {Chart} from 'highcharts-vue'

    export default {
      name: 'stocks',
      props: {
        msg: String
      },
      data () {
        return {
          chartOptions: {
              mySeries: [],
              info: {},
              updateArgs: [true, true, true],
              series: [{
                  data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
                }],
             }
          }, 
        }
      }, //data

      components: {
        highcharts: Chart 
      },

      methods: {
        updateSeries() {

          for (var i = 0; i < this.info.stock_prices.length; i++) {
          this.mySeries.push([this.info.stock_prices[i].volume]);
          i++
          } 


          data: this.mySeries

        }
      }, //methods

      async created () {
        this.info = await appService.getPosts();
        this.updateSeries()
      }, //async created

} //export default
```

I would like to obviously wait for all my data from my API (in the appService component) to load and then use it to create the updated series, but I am not sure that is actually what is happening.

Perhaps an important note: If I replace `data: this.mySeries` in my method with something like `data: [10,10,10,10,10,10]` it is still unsuccessful - no errors and the series is not being updated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is async created hook actually work?

Comment: Yes it does work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice, that your data doesn't contain chartOptions. Also, in `updateSeries()` you are updating data which refers to nothing. It should be something like the example below:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <highcharts :options="chartOptions" :updateArgs="[true, false]" ref="highcharts"></highcharts>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import appService from '../stock_prices'
    import {Chart} from 'highcharts-vue'

    export default {
      name: 'stocks',
      props: {
        msg: String
      },
      data () {
        return {
          mySeries: [],
          info: {},
          updateArgs: [true, true, true],
          chartOptions: {
            series: [{
                data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
            }]
          }
        }
      }, //data

      components: {
        highcharts: Chart 
      },

      methods: {
        updateSeries() {
          for (var i = 0; i < this.info.stock_prices.length; i++) {
            this.mySeries.push([this.info.stock_prices[i].volume]);
          } 

          this.chartOptions.series[0].data: this.mySeries;
        }
      }, //methods

      async created () {
        this.info = await appService.getPosts();
        this.updateSeries()
      }, //async created

} //export default
```

Check this example:

- https://codesandbox.io/s/nw750l07nj

Comment: Oops, forgot to add the chartOptions in this simplified example. But the `this.chartOptions.series[0].data: this.mySeries;` might be what i was missing. I will test and let you know how it went. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. I have tested your solution and it works perfectly. `this.chartOptions.series[0].data = this.mySeries;` did the trick!